# In SSRS How can I do a gradual lookup?

Tags: reporting-services, dataset, lookup

I have two datasets. In each dataset it is possible to have the same item (or even string created by different columns of Dataset1 per row ) multiple times.

How can I 1) do a lookup, 
          2) find the first match between datasets
          3) return the matching value 
          4) and then proceed the lookup with the remaining rows of Dataset2, instead of looking up the second row of Dataset1 with the entire list of Dataset2? . 
I do steps 1-3 but I don't know how I can ensure that all items in dataset2 have been compared.
Thank you

Comment: What query have you developed thus far to try to solve your problem?  Also, it's not clear what your desired output is, can you give an example of what you wan the report to look like?

Comment: This is my current code:
=IIF(Lookup((Fields!item.Value &"_"& CDbl(Fields!UfBuildQty.Value)), (Fields!TcItem.Value &"_"& CDbl(Fields!BuildQty.Value)), "0", "CurrentBOM") = "0", "Black", "Red")

Comment: Both compared strings can be listed multiple times in each dataset. 
I need to find a way that the lookup will find the first match, it will exclude the matched string from the second Dataset 2 list and proceed with the remaining fields in the Dataset (if this is possible).
Thank you all for the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use LookUpSet to retrieve all the values that match criteria from one dataset to another.

> Use **LookupSet** to retrieve a set of values from the specified dataset
>   for a name-value pair where there is a **1-to-many** relationship. For
>   example, for a customer identifier in a table, you can use LookupSet
>   to retrieve all the associated phone numbers for that customer from a
>   dataset that is not bound to the data region.

You might need to use **JOIN** to convert the array to a string.

```
=JOIN(Parameters!Status.Value, ", ")
```